# I m having a problem with the result of my Join table query

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

**This is the code of my queryBuilder**
In database I have two tables:

1. enquiry_table (contains statusId(@ManyToOne) which is a foreign key for enquiry_status_table)
2. enquiry_status_table

```js
 async findByLocation(qParams) {
    return await getRepository(Enquiry).createQueryBuilder('enq')
      .where({ location: qParams.location })
      .select(['enq.id', 'enq.location', 'enqStatus.name'])
      .leftJoin('enq.status', 'enqStatus')
     .getMany()
  }
```

With the above code I get following Results

```js
{
    "id": 5,
    "location": "Karnataka",
    "status": {  <-- This is what I m getting currently with the above code
        "name": "CANCELLED"
    }
  },
```

```js
{
    "id": 5,
    "location": "Karnataka",
    "status": "CANCELLED" <-- this is what I m expecting
},
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add transient property like 'statusName' on enquiry_table entity.

I guess you already have property named 'status' for enquiry_status_table, so I recommended name 'statusName'.

```
@Column({ select: false, update: false, insert: false })
statusName: string;
```

and use `addSelect` on queryBuilder

```
async findByLocation(qParams) {
  return await getRepository(Enquiry).createQueryBuilder('enq')
    .where({ location: qParams.location })
    .select(['enq.id', 'enq.location'])
    .addSelect('enqStatus.name', 'statusName')
    .leftJoin('enq.status', 'enqStatus')
    .getMany()
}
```

and this is expected result

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "location": "Karnataka",
  "statusName": "foo"
},
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it breaks database normalization rules :(
I am planning to use interceptor to transform my response object
So, any solution based on lodash library to transform this object would also be welcomed

Answer (score 0):

I got one solution:

```js
getRepository(Enquiry).createQueryBuilder('enq')
      .select(['enq.id AS id', 'enq.location AS location', 'enqStatus.name AS status'])
      .leftJoin('enq.status', 'enqStatus')
      .where(enquiryReq)
      .getRawMany() <-- I returned raw data and put alias to each field :)
```